# How can I remove active topic?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I wanted to use a python script to record a bag instead of using the command line in terminal.
My script is based on [how record rosbag with python](https://answers.ros.org/question/286871/how-record-rosbag-with-python/). However, the recorded topic stay active in the topic list even after I kill the process with Ctrl+C.

The code snippet is as follows:

```
import subprocess, shlex, psutil
command = "ros2 bag record -o subset /sensor/position"
command = shlex.split(command)
rosbag_proc = subprocess.Popen(command)
```

How can I fix this?

Any help is appreciated

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/409553/how-can-i-remove-active-topic?/) by [Ima](https://answers.ros.org/users/122096/ima/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2022-11-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2022-11-18**:
Follow the answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

You can write a proper node for recoding a bag file.

You can follow a tutorial for recording a bag file using the python ros2 node.

https://docs.ros.org/en/galactic/Tutorials/Advanced/Recording-A-Bag-From-Your-Own-Node-Py.html

> I kill the process

Instead, you can unsubscribe to that by using the following line.

`self.Node.destroy_subscription(self,self.subscriber)`

---

Originally posted by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) with karma: 1622 on 2022-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ima](https://answers.ros.org/users/122096/ima/) on 2022-11-18**:
Thanks for the reply! I, however, tried writing a ros2 node for recording a rosbag but Ros2 foxy doesn't provide the package rosbag2_py.

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2022-11-18**:
Have a look in the future branch you will be able to get rosbag2_py

https://github.com/ros2/rosbag2/tree/foxy-future

https://github.com/ros2/rosbag2/issues/983

If you got your answer then accept the answer by pressing tick button.

**Comment by [Ima](https://answers.ros.org/users/122096/ima/) on 2022-11-21**:
I can't change the whole branch to a new one, and what I'm looking for is removing the remaining active topics from the topic list

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2022-11-21**:
Clone the git repo, then after change the branch to foxy, build it. I think you will be ready to go.